# Embed Excel Sheet into form

Tags: c#, excel, controls

OK, I need to embed an Excel template document into a winform (retaining all the formatting), change some values, printpreview it, then print it to either PDF or a printer. And I need to do it without spending any of the boss's cash.

I tried embedding the standard Excel COM stuff, but the IDE (C# Express 2010) didn't like it and crashed (the Office control didn't seem to do much and accessing an XLS in a webbrowser only worked occasionally)

So I'm guessing that I'm looking at a third party open source Excel control?

In fact theoretically it could be any grid-type format as long as I can do similar formatting to Excel and make it look all pretty for the client.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could get the functionality you want with the DSOFramer control. This was a small control that Microsoft provided long, long time ago, and has since decomissioned from their site. It still works perfectly well, though. You can download the control from here:

http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Developer-Support-Office-Framer-Control-Sample-KB-311765/3000-2206_4-10732960.html

Comment: Thanks, this might be what I want. Having trouble getting the UI to work, but other than that it seems to display the document well enough. If I can get the UI to play ball I'll mark this as the answer.