# Having trouble getting color scale conditional formatting from Excel file to show up in embedded spreadsheet in Windows Form

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, spreadsheetgear

I have a Windows Form that currently displays a spreadsheet that is editable.  I have functionality to allow the user to browse for an Excel file to import to the spreadsheet in the Form view.  It is important that an Excel file with a Color Scale Conditional Format be imported with the colors of the cells, as a result of the conditional format, to show up in the embedded spreadsheet.

I am currently using SpreadsheetGear's WorkbookView, but I have also discovered that SpreadsheetGear does not handle the conditional formatting with a color scale.  Is there a way to either,

1. save the resulting cell colors from my excel object to apply later to the cells in my SpreadsheetGear object?  Or,
2. Use a control in the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace that DOES handle the color scaling conditional formatting found in existing excel files?

Comment: There's an answer here which might be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765128/embed-excel-sheet-into-form

Comment: Thank you Tim, I will give this a shot and let you know how it goes for me.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: @JakeSmith: See if this helps? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/28a3c788-4ed8-41a9-af8a-3138b4916b8d#982184ea-4ba1-4b85-bf18-83ab5c7f1aed I haven't tested the `Edraw Office Viewer Component` for conditional formatting though.

Comment: @JakeSmith: Seeing this http://www.edrawsoft.com/embed-excel-vb.php it seems like it does support Conditional Format :)

Comment: SpreadsheetGear 2017 and later has vastly enhanced its support for conditional formatting--supporting all the features available in current versions of Excel (Excel 2019 at the moment). If you are having trouble with Conditional Formatting and using an older version such as SpreadsheetGear 2012 / V7 or earlier, try upgrading to see if the issue goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpreadsheetGear is caught up with Excel's features from Excel 2007 and earlier. It will be a while before SpreadsheetGear implements the Conditional Formatting that includes Color Scaling because that wasn't added to Excel until after the 2007 addition.